# Ceph log format info

Tags: logging, documentation, monitoring, ceph

I have been tasked with creating a parser for Ceph to use with a new Scalyr installation.
I would like to break the logs down by field as much as possible to facilitate complex searches later on but I am unable to locate anything on the field contents and there are a couple in every log I have no idea what are used for.

Anyone have a resource they can point me at for this?

Thanks, not technical but frustrating anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be broken out into two tasks.

1. Getting the parser logic on the Scalyr side
2. Getting the names of the Ceph fields

On the Scalyr Side:
The log format will look something like this.

```
{
patterns:{
   tsPattern: "[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+"
}.

formats:[

   { 
     format: "$timestamp=tsPattern$ $var2$ $rest_of_line$"
   }
]
}
```

If you provide a log sample, I will create the rest of the parser for you.

For more help on parsing:

1. You can go to [scalyr.com/parsers](https://scalyr.com/parsers) and create a task for the scalyr support team to help with the parser. Click the "Create for Me" button, and they will return the parser.
2. Here is the [documentation](https://app.scalyr.com/help/parsing-logs) for parsing which I am assuming you have seen.
3. Here is a [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPt4mdBY9Ng&list=PL-cmxw5jVDx9b2Zj80J3QksG4kD9Y6caW) you may not have seen

Comment: Awesome and thanks but it's not the coding I am having trouble with, it's the lack of documentation of the fields in the logs.

Comment: Ya I noticed that too when I tried to look up the log formats in their docs to provide actual field names and patterns. 

Hoped someone who knew Ceph would have responded by now but since some systems log formats can vary from one configuration to another, maybe if you provided a few log lines with sensitive info redacted, someone who knows Ceph would be able to provide the field names. Then it is just a matter of naming them in the parser.

Comment: try deploying a ceph in container https://github.com/ceph/ceph-container with the scalyr agent. That should expose the logs. It seems you can start off with a built in Scalyr syslog parser first